# Populate DataGrid using SqlDataReader with null

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sqldatareader

I use **SqlDataReader** to write database rows onto **DataGrid** in a while-loop (instead of binding SqlDataReader or DataTable due to memory issue), but receive null exception when SqlDataReader hit a null field. I had tried the `??` operator which does not work. Is there an easier or more elegant way instead of checking each return value in a if-else statement?

```
while (sqlDataReader.Read()) 
{
   myDataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem
   {
       Column01 = rdr.GetInt32(0) ?? "EMPTY",
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) on the column will allow you to check for null values:

```
Column01 = rdr.IsDBNull(0) ? "EMPTY" : rdr.GetInt32(0).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution, implemented as a reusable method extension

```
public static Int32 GetInt32(this IDataRecord dr, int index, Int32 @default)
{
   object obj = dr[index];
   if (null == obj || obj is DBNull) return @default;

   return dr.GetInt32(index);
   //return Convert.ToInt32(obj);//alternatively
}
```

Ideally you make yourself method extensions for all relevant types. @default can be used to specify, which value should appear in the NULL case.